# Yii2 delete file from folder

Tags: yii2

public function actionDelete($id)

{

```
    $model=$this->findModel($id);         
    unlink($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/../../uploads/".$model->image);
```

OR

```
    unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../uploads/'.$model->image);
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();    
    return $this->redirect(['index']);       
}
```

Comment: `echo 'Since you only posted code, I\'ll do the same. What is your question? Are you asking which of the two code stumps (document_root or dirname) to use?';`. If that's the case, use [`\Yii::getAlias()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-concept-aliases.html)

Comment: try with this     unlink(Yii::$app->basePath . '/../../uploads/' . $model->image);

Answer (score 6):

Use PHP function unlink()

Then go to your model controller

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $data = Document::findOne($id);
    unlink(Yii::$app->basePath . '/web/' . $data->file_name);
    $this->findModel($id)->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you define a alias, in common/config/bootstrap.php and add this line top of the file

```
Yii::setAlias('@root', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'));
```

and then:

```
unlink(Yii::getAlias('@root') . '/uploads/'. $model->image);
```